# unable to copy binary string from table to notepad

Tags: sql-server

I have stored 391603 characters JSON document in the column, when I am trying to copy it and past in notepad full file is not coming. I can only see 43679 characters.

[image]

how to resolve this..

Answer (score 2):

in SQL Server Management Studio, go to the "Tools" menu, click on "Options", then navigate to "Query Results", "SQL Server", "Results to Grid", and modify the "Non XML data" option to whatever setting you desire.

[image]

[Aaron](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) has a great post about how to chunk output so you can see it all, regardless of how large a piece of text you're dealing with [at MSSQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/)

However, in SSMS 18, I am able to get substantially larger amounts of text to copy-and-paste from the results window using the option I detailed above.  There are at least a couple of caveats you might need to know about before it starts working.

1. After you change the "Maximum Characters Retrieved" for Non-XML Data, it only takes effect for *new* query windows.  i.e. you must open a new query window before you can get more than 65535 characters to copy-and-paste.
2. If you are testing this by generating a series of characters with replicate, ensure you use an explicit "max" data type, as in `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)`.  If you run `SELECT REPLICATE('X', 131072)` for example, the resulting string will only be 8,000 characters in length because the implicit conversion is to a varchar type, not a varchar(max) type.  Running this, however, will generate a string that is 131072 characters in length:

   ```
   SELECT [string] = REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'X'), 131072)
       , [length] = LEN(REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'X'), 131072))
   ```

   The results:

   [image]

I modified the "Maximum Characters Retrieved" value to 131072, then opened a new query window and pasted in the code above, hit F5, and got the results you see above.  I then cvopied the value shown in the "string" column to the clipboard, then pasted it into another new query window, where I confirmed the length of the string with the following code:

```
SELECT LEN(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(due to the 30,000 character limitation on questions,  not all the "X"s are shown here) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'))
```

```
╔══════════════════╗
║ (No column name) ║
╠══════════════════╣
║           131072 ║
╚══════════════════╝
```

Comment: So at some point they doubled the limit? Could you go beyond 131,072 Max?